# How do I access to CKeditor Image resizer web element in menu pop up?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x, fckeditor, ckeditor.net

[Image resizer CK editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBJh1.png)

I need to get a way to obtain the html web element tag and attributes of the menu popup options to resize the image. But when I Inspect the element it does not select any html element, I only can acces to the image, not to the option items of the popup menu to resize it.

[Inspection of html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/317NJ.png)

So can you help me with this?

This is the page where I am obtaining this example: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/images/images-resizing.html

Thanks in advance